# Wordpress - WP_query sort with 2 diffrent values?

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, date, search

I'm making a list of some posts, and I want to sort it by 2 `Meta_values(dates) in ASC`

So fx. if i have the dates below:

```
- 23-08-2016 -> 23-08-2016
- 23-08-2016 -> 22-08-2016
- 23-08-2016 -> 24-08-2016
- 22-08-2016 -> 24-08-2016
```

I want it to sort first by the first date, and then i want these sorted by the second, so i want the code above sorted like this:

```
- 22-08-2016 -> 24-08-2016 
- 23-08-2016 -> 22-08-2016
- 23-08-2016 -> 23-08-2016
- 23-08-2016 -> 24-08-2016
```

Is there any way I can do this using a WP_query? or do I have to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a secondary `orderby` like this:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'date1 date2',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Display posts sorted by `date1` with a fallback to post `date2`, in ascending order:

Comment: But that will not order my dates as asked will it? i just tried and it ordered sometimes by date2 first :(